# Codeigniter ajax No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: html, ajax, codeigniter, request

...first of all, I already try a lot of things to solve this problem. And nothing bring me results...I already try to put this code on the controller on .htaccess and nothing happens...

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

I really don't know what's happening, the json data I need to show it's been received without problems...it's very frustrating, so please if someone can bring me a solution I will appreaciate it very much...I spend 3 days trying to solve this. Here is the error and the code...cheers.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/papo/bodyface/admin/load_image. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

AJAX JSON OBJECT

```
[{"IMAGE_ID":"11","IMAGE_NAME":"MUJER-GUANTES1.png","IMAGE_TITTLE":"veremos que onda","IMAGE_CONTENT":"un nuevo titulo para bodyface","IMAGE_TYPE":"1"},{"IMAGE_ID":"12","IMAGE_NAME":"tecnologia8.png","IMAGE_TITTLE":"","IMAGE_CONTENT":"","IMAGE_TYPE":"2"},{"IMAGE_ID":"16","IMAGE_NAME":"tecnologia71.png","IMAGE_TITTLE":"","IMAGE_CONTENT":"","IMAGE_TYPE":"2"},{"IMAGE_ID":"17","IMAGE_NAME":"tecnologia12.png","IMAGE_TITTLE":"","IMAGE_CONTENT":"","IMAGE_TYPE":"2"},{"IMAGE_ID":"18","IMAGE_NAME":"tecnologia4.png","IMAGE_TITTLE":"","IMAGE_CONTENT":"","IMAGE_TYPE":"2"},{"IMAGE_ID":"19","IMAGE_NAME":"tecnologia3.png","IMAGE_TITTLE":"","IMAGE_CONTENT":"","IMAGE_TYPE":"2"}]
```

AJAX REQUEST

```
$.ajax({
  url: baseurl+'admin/load_image',
  type: 'POST',
    function(data) {
        var p = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(p, function(i, item) {

                if (item.IMAGE_TYPE == 1) {
                      $('.slides').append(

                          '<li>'+
                          '<img src="'+baseurl+'public/img/'+item.IMAGE_NAME+'">'+
                          '<div class="caption center-align">'+
                          '<h3>'+item.IMAGE_TITTLE+'</h3>'+
                          '<h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">'+item.IMAGE_CONTENT+'</h5>'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '</li>');
                }

                if (item.IMAGE_TYPE == 2) {
                      $('.slider-for').slick('slickAdd','<div><img src="'+baseurl+'public/img/'+item.IMAGE_NAME+'"></div>');
                      $('.product').slick('slickAdd','<div><img style="max_height:10%;max_width:10%;" src="'+baseurl+'public/img/'+item.IMAGE_NAME+'"></div>');
                }
            });

            $('.slider').slider({
              full_width: true,
              height:     650,
              indicators: false
            }); //materialize slider initialization

    }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider">
                <ul class="slides">

                </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: is `url: baseurl+'admin/load_image',` the same domain you are requesting from?

Comment: yeah it is...I'm getting the json object with data from database without problem...but it's not showing up on html.

Answer (score 0):

maybee you can try add this on the bottom of type,`crossDomain: true` if you are not same sites